# assignment between array elements using boost multi_array iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-keyword, assign, boost-multi-array

Working on a Kubuntu 14.04 system with gcc 4.8.4 I ran into the following problem:

Using std:vector, I can assign between vector elements via an iterator:

```
std::vector<float> v ;
v.push_back(0.0) ;
v.push_back(1.0) ;
auto vv = v.begin() ;
vv[0] = vv[1] ;
assert ( v[0] == v[1] ) ;
```

Using a boost multi_array, this fails:

```
typedef boost::multi_array<float, 1> array_type; 
boost::array<array_type::index, 1> shape = {{ 2 }};
array_type a(shape) ;
a[0] = 0.0 ;
a[1] = 1.0 ;
auto aa = a.begin() ;
aa[0] = aa[1] ;
assert ( a[0] == a[1] ) ; // fails, a[0] is unmodified
```

I can work around this using a different idiom like

```
aa[0] = *(aa+1) ;
```

But the code I want to use with the multi_array is written using assignments of the type that doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: It is 2024 and this is still a bug in Boost.MultiArray. I tried a similar library which doesn't have the bug. https://godbolt.org/z/4W5o1jG8r

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the iterator involved in `operator[]` for `boost::multi_array` is an [input iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/utility/Collection.html), which is not required to be mutable.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was complete nonsense! (Though input iterators really don't require op-`[]` to exist.)

Comment: Indeed. The boost docu states that 'This is an iterator over the values of A. If NumDims == 1, then it models Random Access Iterator. Otherwise it models Random Access Traversal Iterator, Readable Iterator, Writable Iterator, and Output Iterator.' So in this case it would be a Random Access Iterator.

Comment: The OP code should work. If it didn’t it was a bug in BMA

Comment: You pulled the wrong documentation. mulit_array fulfills the concept of MutableMultiArray which, in this sense is more than a Collection.